# Select a single value with multiple matches

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

Below two sections of one XML file.

I'm trying to match a node with name cutSeven and select its first childnodes text.

Matching path is unknown, so each XML has similar info in different positions.

I'm working with several XMLs includes those informations and I'm on the way to create an automatically updatable overview for it.

Input XML

```
<Transform>
    <param name="originalHeader">
        <path>$header</path>
    </param>
    <param name="cutSeven">
            <path>"fi.siikjin.exitorder.seasam.accesscontrol.k1"</path>
    </param>
</Transform>
.
.
.
<Transform>
    <param name="originalHeader">
        <path>$header</path>
    </param>
    <param name="cutSeven">
            <path>"fi.siikjin.exitorder.seasam.accesscontrol.k1.accesscontrol_k1.accesscontrol"</path>
    </param>
</Transform>
```

My expression

```
<xsl:value-of select="//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'cutSeven']/parent::*[1]"/>
```

brings me to output:

```
<path>"fi.siikjin.exitorder.seasam.sec.accesscontrol.k1"</path>
<path>"fi.siikjin.exitorder.seasam.sec.accesscontrol.k1.accesscontrol_k1.accesscontrol"</path>
```

Expected:

```
<path>"fi.siikjin.exitorder.seasam.accesscontrol.k1"</path>
```

How can I select only the first matching node and ignore further matches? Or acording to me, output only 1 value.
Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//*[@name = 'cutSeven']` selects all elements with that `name` attribute value and `(//*[@name = 'cutSeven'])[1]` only the first of those elements.

Comment: Thank you! `(//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'cutSeven'])[1]/parent::*` working for me